# unity проблемка

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

ошибка:

```
UnityException: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.CheckSafeProjectOverwrite (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <14dbc2b0bcd24b728c83d8db8356e21e>:0)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <b17f35b08b864a3ca09a7032b437596e>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <b17f35b08b864a3ca09a7032b437596e>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <b17f35b08b864a3ca09a7032b437596e>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <b17f35b08b864a3ca09a7032b437596e>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

просто тупо не понимаю что она значит единственное что я понял что что-то случилось с файлом MicrosoftVisualStudioSolution

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на кнопку Build Settings есть такой пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо до этого Вы создавали билд со включенной галочкой, а теперь пытаетесь создать без нее. Есть 3 решения:

1. Включить галочку;
2. Удалить из папки предыдущего билда все файлы связанные с решением;
3. Сделать билд в другую папку.